# Simple POST using urllib with Python 3.3

Tags: python, post, urllib, python-3.3

I'm participating in a hash-breaking contest and I'm trying to automate posting strings to an html form and getting the hash score back. So far I've managed to get SOMETHING posted to the url, but its not the exact string I'm expecting, and thus the value returned for the hash is way off from the one obtained by just typing in the string manually.

```
import urllib.parse, urllib.request

url = "http://almamater.xkcd.com/?edu=una.edu"
data = "test".encode("ascii")
header = {"Content-Type":"application/octet-stream"}
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data, header)
f = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
print(f.read())
#parse f to pull out hash
```

I obtain the following hash from the site:

```
0fff9563bb3279289227ac77d319b6fff8d7e9f09da1247b72a0a265cd6d2a62645ad547ed8193db48cff847c06494a03f55666d3b47eb4c20456c9373c86297d630d5578ebd34cb40991578f9f52b18003efa35d3da6553ff35db91b81ab890bec1b189b7f52cb2a783ebb7d823d725b0b4a71f6824e88f68f982eefc6d19c6
```

This differs considerably from what I expected, which is what you get if you type in "test" (no quotes) into the form:

```
e21091dbb0d61bc93db4d1f278a04fe1a51165fb7262c7da31f886ae09ff3e04c41483c500db2792c59742958d8f7f39fe4f4f2cdc7940b7b25e3289b89d344e06f76305b9de525933b5df5dae2a37388f82cf76374fe363587acfb49b9d2c8fc131ef4a32c762be083b07330989b298d60e312f56a6b8a4c0f53c9b59864fb7
```

Obviously the code isn't doing what I'm expecting it to do. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit your form data, it also includes the field name, so when you submit "test" the data submitted actually looks like "hashable=test". Try changing your data like this:

```
data = "hashable=test".encode("ascii")
```

or alternatively:

```
data = urllib.parse.urlencode({'hashable': 'test'})
```